# Reporting tool for .Net compact framework 3.5

Tags: pdf, compact-framework, report, reporting, .net-cf-3.5

I'm looking for a reporting tool for .NET compact Framework 3.5. 
I need a tool that would generate a pdf from a previously designed report.
I found a topic where somone claimed they used fyireporting on mobile devices, but when i try to use Visual Studio gives me this error

> "The type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

I can't add this because it is not a dll from compact framework. 
Is there any reporting tool for .net CF?

Comment: Where is this example? I'm not sure what **fyireporting** is.

Comment: This is not something you'd normally do on the device, it has a small screen and limited support for viewing the reports.  I recommend placing report generation on the server.